# Is 5V@3A really possible using a Type-A plug charger?

Tags: power-supply, usb-c

I have a 18 W capable phone wall charger that I'd like to use to power my 5V@1.5A hobby circuit, it has a Type-A plug in it and the label states the following ratings:

- 5V@3A
- 9V@2A
- 12V@1.5A

[image]

So after reading this post: https://forum.digikey.com/t/simple-way-to-use-usb-type-c-to-get-5v-at-up-to-3a-15w/7016

[image]

I went ahead and added the necessary 5K1 Ohm resistors to the appropriate pins with assistance from this question [JRC-B008 for USB-C microcontroller power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/595590/148272) because I'm using the same plug, but used regular 1/4 Watt +0.5% axial resistors instead of SMDs.

[image]

But it didn't work and I'm confused. The post in the Digikey blog suggests that it is possible although not recommended:

> One thing that is not recommended to ever do is use or build USB-A
> Male to USB Type-C adapter cables that have the Rd resistor built in
> to spoof the specification to draw 3A. An engineer over a Google has
> well documented the results of manufacturers that hack the USB Type-C
> spec to negative results, sometimes catastrophic.

But this other question [Is it sufficient to put 5.1k pulldowns on CC1 and CC2 of USBC to get 5V 1.5A?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/642976/148272) says that Type-A to Type-C cables just won't work, even with the resistors.

Here's what I tried and the results:

**Type-A plug charger with Type-A to Type-C cable with unmodded plug**

Voltage drops to something very low and it pulls about 1.2 A from it.

**Same charger, same cable with modded plug**

Voltage drops to about 3 V but I can only draw about 100 mA

For the record: **Type-A plug charger with Type-A-to-C converter dongle and Type-C-to-C cable**

Same result as above.

**Apple 20 W charger with Type-C-to-C cable with modded plug**

Same result as above.

**Apple 65 W laptop charger with Type-C-to-C cable with modded plug**

Same result as above.

Both apple chargers say (USB-PD) in the label so I assume they just won't work, but...

If Type-A to Type-C 5V@3A is not possible as per the spec, how does this charger do it? And why does my all Type-C setup not work either?

Comment: Per web search, the charger "GAR092" does have a Type-A RECEPTACLE, not a "plug". And it comes with Type-A to C" cable. Your  "5V@1.5A hobby circuit" should have no problem whatsoever to get 1.5A out of Type-A port of this charger at default 5V, unless your "5V@1.5A hobby circuit" consumes significantly more and causes the charger to drop off. And keep in mind that a "charger" is generally not a good and stable power supply in its normal sense.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I used plug because I keep seeing it be commonly used in other places, maybe you prefer DFP? please spare using caps or quote _5V@1.5A hobby circuit_ over and over (it is rude and condescending). I know what came in the box (a cheap charger and a cable) and yes, I tried using a proper (albeit not ultra expensive, professional grade) bench power supply and it does indeed not need more than 1.5 A at any given time (except maybe for a few ms at power up?), I tested using said psu capped at 2A beforehand hence why I thought about using a 5V@3A capable USB charger for it...

Comment: "I know it came in the box..." - but we don't know that. Again, you are modifying some plug, but you don't tell which port/receptacle you a planning to plug it in (from web links, the charger comes with Type-A port only). So your request lacks essential information to deal with. Please confirm that your charger GAR092 doea have only a Type-A port, and we can continue to debug your problem.

Comment: Also take a look at this topic, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695888/117785

Comment: By the chance, are you trying to power a DC-DC converter with a 220uF input capacitor, no?

Answer (score 0):

The method mentioned in the article you linked is for chargers having USB-C PD capabilities. Yours is not one of them.

Yours appears to be a [Qualcomm Quick Charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge) compatible device *(The latest version is 5 but yours should support at least version 2.0 or 3.0)* so you may want to look for methods to "trick" a QC3 charger from its D+ and D– lines to get higher voltages or maximum available power.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if that is the case, why didn't both Apple chargers using a C-to-C cable work either? They explicitly say USB-PD in the label.